# DataFormat in CellStyle (Apache POI) is exported differently on Windows and Mac

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I export a excel file using data formats in cell styles of Apache POI. It works so far, but the output of formatted values are differently on Windows and Mac.

For example I set this format on a cell style: #,##0.00. 
While on Mac it is working for every number value, on Windows I receive strange results in the output like '0.00 instead of 0.00 or 2314'324.59 instead of 2'314'324.59.

Does anybody know if there are differences I have to consider?

Comment: I think excel uses the system separators by default. That is nothing that you can change by altering the export

Comment: Did you try setting an explicit locale? Did you try changing the locale/location on both machines to match?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The issue from @XtremeBaumer was correct :)